# File Upload using HTTP protocol through java socket

Tags: java, sockets, http, multipartform-data

I am trying to understand how HTTP protocol works, So I tried to add headers manually to java Socket to send a request to httpbin.org as shown below:

```
        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(/*socket Outputstream*/)     
        wr.write("POST post HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        wr.write("Host: httpbin.org\r\n");
        wr.write("Accept: */*\r\n");
        wr.write("Content-Length: "+data.length()+"\r\n");
        wr.write("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundary67\r\n");
        wr.write("\r\n"); 
        wr.write(data); 
        wr.flush();
```

In above code `data` is the payload of HTTP request that looks exactly as below:

```
   ---WebKitFormBoundary67
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"
   value1
   ---WebKitFormBoundary67
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field2"; filename="example.txt"

   Java is better when it run long
   ---WebKitFormBoundary67--
```

But the server httpbin.org is not identifying any files attached, am I missing anything?

Comment: I don't see how this shows how http protocol works? Just arbitrary server configurations etc and preferences?

Comment: @marshalcraft I think this is what a typical browser does when you submit a form with file-upload in a web page. A protocol is noting but a set of rules two systems agree to communicate without any hassles. Above question has tried to follow rules defined in [RFC 2046](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046), so any HTTP server can recognise what kind of information I am sending to it. As I failed to follow the conventions properly the targeting server has failed to identify what data I am exactly trying to send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multipart/form-data` is a multipart MIME message as defined in [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046). The basic structure of a multipart MIME message in an example of a `multipart/form-data` message looks like this:

```
Content-type:  multipart/form-data; boundary=foo

--foo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=key1

abcde
--foo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=key2; filename=foo.txt

01234
--foo--
```

As you can see, the boundary `foo` is defined in the boundary attribute, is used as delimiter between the parts with `--foo` and is used as the final boundary as `--foo--`.

Your code instead defines the boundary not as `foo` but as `--foo` and then tries to still use only `--foo` as a separator between the parts. To correct your code you would either need to set the boundary to only `-WebKitFormBoundary67` instead of `---WebKitFormBoundary67`, or use `-----WebKitFormBoundary67` as separator instead of only `---WebKitFormBoundary67`.

Comment: Thank you, I realised that I have to give only  `--` before the delimiter in the payload to separate the parameters.

Comment: Also, in the original `data` shown, there is a blank line missing between the MIME headers and MIME body for `field1`, like there is one present for `field2`. That means `value1` gets treated as an unknown MIME header for `field1` instead of its text value